# “quoique” vs. “bien que”

Tags: usage, conjonctions

Is there any difference between “quoique“ and “bien que”?

I have found two random examples, but my knowledge of French is not good enough to understand if they express the same meaning or not.

> Il y écrivait encore des opéras : mais c'est avec peine qu'il les
>   faisait représenter ; et le dernier, bien que composé à Venise, fut
>   joué à Londres où il n'eut point de succès.
>
> C'est moi qui ai fait la faute d'ailleurs, et quoique les pages ne
>   fussent pas numérotées, je crois avoir mis chaque feuillet à sa place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les conjonctions de subordination « [bien que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien) », « [encore que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encore) », « [malgré que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malgr%C3%A9) », « [quoique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoique) » sont essentiellement synonymes. Elles marquent la [concession](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/CONCESS.htm). On peut quand même trouver quelques nuances.

« Bien que » est la plus courante. S'il ne faut en retenir qu'une, retiens celle-là. « Quoique » et « encore que » sont relativement rares dans le registre familier.

Ces conjonctions impliquent une opposition entre les deux propositions. Je pense que « bien que » et « malgré que » s'emploient plutôt lorsque c'est la proposition principale qui domine, et « quoique » et « encore que » lorsque c'est la proposition subordonnée qui domine. Cela dit, les emplois se recouvrent largement. Exemples (tirés du TLF lorsqu'ils sont attribués, de mon crû sinon) :

> Ne faudrait-il quand même pas lui faire une petite visite, **bien qu**'il soit aussi distant et insensible qu'un cadavre? [Duhamel]
>    Rastignac fut forcé de le remercier, **quoique** depuis les mots aigrement échangés, le jour où il était revenu de chez Madame de Beauséant, cet homme lui fût insupportable. [Balzac]
>   Elle tira ensuite d'une armoire pratiquée dans le mur plusieurs [désirables], mais dont la jeune actrice ne voulut point, **encore que** la sienne fût défraîchie et fripée, ... [Gautier]
>   Il est venu à la réunion, **bien qu**'il n'ait pas beaucoup de temps.
>   Il dit être venu à la réunion, **encore que** je ne me souviens pas l'y avoir vu.

« Malgré que » est assez rare à l'écrit, et souvent considéré comme incorrect (la plupart des prescriptivistes le refusent). Bien qu'il soit attesté chez plusieurs auteurs, même à l'oral, il faut s'attendre à être repris si on l'utilise.

Comment: « Malgré que » est correct au Québec.  En France, la règle la plus répandue concernant son usage est je crois « uniquement suivi du verbe avoir (et pas l'auxiliaire). »  Il serait donc correct de dire « J'ai pas eu de chance, malgré que j'en aie d'habitude. »

Comment: @Axioplase Il n'y a pas de cas particulier en France pour le verbe avoir. « Malgré que j'en aie » est une expression figée vieillie, qui veut dire en gros « contre mon gré ». Pour les gens qui considèrent *malgré que* comme incorrect, ta phrase est aussi incorrecte qu'une autre.

Comment: hum, alors je ne sais plus d'où j'avais tiré ça.  Merci de la correction.

Answer (score 6):

On utilise souvent « quoique » pour indiquer un changement d’avis.

> J’aimerais bien aller en ville avec vous! Quoique par ce temps...

Dans cet exemple, la personne n’est plus si sûre de vouloir aller en ville après une brève réflexion.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux expressions ont le même sens, cependant on utilise généralement la première "quoique" dans une phrase négative et la seconde "bien que" dans une phrase positive.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr pour ta deuxième affirmation. Tu as des sources?

Comment: Malheureusement, non.  Ce n'est peut-être qu'une question de goût, après tout.

Answer (score 0):

Ces deux expressions sont essentiellement équivalentes.