# Le subjonctif sert-il à quelque chose ?

Tags: conjugaison, verbes, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Est-ce que l'on peut trouver des phrases où le subjonctif a un sens ? C'est-à-dire : peut-on me citer une ou plusieurs phrase(s) avec un verbe dont le choix de mode (subjonctif ou indicatif) peut changer le sens de la phrase ?

Comment: Ah, comme j'eusse aimé qu'il fût plus employé !

Comment: @F'x, Oh le beau conditionnel ! :-)

Comment: Il y a une différence entre ton titre et ta question : oui, le subjonctif sert à quelque chose, il est indispensable dans certaines constructions de phrases, comme démontré plus bas. Le challenge (intéressant) de la question est différent, et ne remet pas en cause son utilité.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En général, le subjonctif apparaît dans une proposition relative, et c'est la conjonction de subordination ou le verbe de la proposition principale qui détermine le mode (subjonctif ou indicatif) du verbe de la relative. Mais il existe quand même des cas où la grammaire autorise les deux modes.

Avec certains verbes, l'indicatif indique une catégorie dont on sait et on affirme qu'elle n'est pas vide, alors que le subjonctif porte un doute sur l'existence d'un élément dans la catégorie. (Exemple inspiré de celui cité sur [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif).)

> Je cherche le titre d'un livre dont le narrateur **est** un chien. (Je sais que ce livre existe puisque je l'ai lu, mais j'ai oublié le titre et je veux le retrouver.)
>   Je cherche le titre d'un livre dont le narrateur **soit** un chien. (Je ne sais pas s'il en existe, mais si oui j'aimerais avoir son titre pour pouvoir le lire.)

*Quoique* peut avoir le sens de *bien que* (concession, dans laquelle la phrase principale domine), et est suivi du subjonctif. Il peut aussi avoir le sens d'*encore que* (concession, dans laquelle la subordonnée domine). (Voir sur ce site [“quoique” vs. “bien que”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/196/quoique-vs-bien-que).) (Exemples cités par le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoique).)

> **Quoique** rien ne l'**obligeât** plus à terminer son article − peut-être même à cause de cela − il se remit avec entrain au travail. (Roger Martin du Gard, *Les Thibault*, 1936)
>   Tu pourrais balader des grenades ou n'importe quelle pétoire **quoique** j'**ai** dans l'idée que tu n'es pas doué pour le tir au pigeon. (Jean-Paul Sartre, *Mains sales*, 1948)

Au passage, il y a des constructions qui permettent indifféremment le subjonctif ou l'indicatif, sans nuance de sens (mais avec éventuellement une nuance de niveau de langue). Par exemple *tout ivre qu'il **soit*** ou *tout ivre qu'il **est*** ([TLF tout² B](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout)) (synonymes de *bien qu'il soit ivre*, avec la nuance que la concession s'applique même si le degré d'ivresse est élevé).

Comment: Dans la même idée de « doute » voir aussi *avant que* + subjonctif vs. *après que* + indicatif

Comment: @cadrian Justement, *avant que* et *après que* sont des exemples de cas où la grammaire impose le mode ([enfin presque](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/avant-que-et-apres-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif), mais il y a peu de locuteurs qui font une différence de sens entre *après que* + ind. et *après que* + subj.).

Comment: [Autre exemple](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#83_strong-em-subordonne-relative-indicatif-ou-subjonctif-em-strong) de différence de sens qui, me semble-t'il, ne s'explique pas par un doute: _C’est le plus jeune conseiller qui a été élu maire_ (on constate que c’est le plus jeune qui a été élu) et _C’est le plus jeune conseiller qui ait été élu maire_ (le locuteur souligne qu’on n’a jamais élu un conseiller plus jeune comme maire).

Answer (score 10):

Que penses-tu de

> Dieu soit loué ! (*(May) god be praised!*)

versus

> Dieu est loué ! (*God is praised!*)

où la première forme est très courante, signifiant que le locuteur souhaite que son dieu soit loué, alors que la deuxième forme, rarement entendue mais quand même naturelle, déclare que le dieu est déjà effectivement loué.

Dans un cas, une requête, dans un autre, l'exposition d'un fait.  Plutôt différent, non ?

Comment: Bon exemple, est c'est le même en anglais.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipédia répond très bien à ton problème :

> Le subjonctif est un mode grammatical exprimant un fait comme pensé ou imaginé (opinions, faits irréels, incertains ou simplement envisagés), par contraste avec l'indicatif qui est censé rapporter les faits réels.
>
> Il semble que je ne puisse pas le faire. (opinion, incertitude)
>
> Je ne peux pas le faire. (constatation)

On voit bien ici que l'indicatif change le sens de la phrase car l'action.
De plus des constructions comme « Il semble que je ne peux pas le faire » sont grammaticalement fausse.

#### Edit suite à commentaire

Je ne sais pas si j'ai bien compris ce principe de « paire minimale, » mais que penses-tu de :

> Que je suis grand !
>
> Que je sois grand !

Le premier exprime toujours une constatation « Oh grand-mère que vous avez de grandes dents » et le second un souhait, une situation qui n'existe pas « Oh grand mère, que vous ayez de grandes dents. »

Je crois cependant que la sémantique du « que » n'est pas la même (et à mon avis ne le sera jamais).

Comment: Peut-être que ma question n'était pas claire. Je sais déjà tout ça, je voulais savoir s'il y avait une paire minimale où le choix de mode, à lui seul, change le sens de la phrase.

Comment: @Brennan une "paire minimale"???

Comment: Deux phrases qui ont chacun un sens différent, et dont la seule différence est la mode du/des verbe(s)

Comment: Par exemple, si « je ne crois pas qu'il est là » et « je ne crois pas qu'il soit là » avaient deux significations différentes, ce serait une paire minimale.

Comment: Je confirme l'intérêt pour la paire minimale, et trouve que le défi a été parfaitement relevé.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, le subjonctif certainement a un sens clair, même en anglais (ce que trop de personnes ne réalisent pas !)  Comparez ces deux phrases :

> C'est important que vous soyez gentil. (It's important that you be kind.)
>   C'est important que vous êtes gentil. (It's important that you are kind.)

Elles ont un sens différent.  La première veut dire que quelqu'un (« vous ») doit être gentil, et ne dit pas si ou non la personne est gentille en ce moment.  La deuxième veut dire que quelqu'un (« vous ») *est* gentil, et ce fait est important.

Comment: « C'est important que vous êtes gentil » sonne mal à mes oreilles. Je crois que la proximité avec la construction subjonctive fait qu'on n'emploie pas (ou rarement) l'indicatif comme ça…

Comment: Mauvais exemple. 'C'est important que vous êtes gentil.'  n'est pas une forme correcte. Et 'C'est important que vous soyez gentil' peut avoir les deux sens (hélas !) indiqués suivant le contexte.