# Quelles sont les différences entre « quoique », « bien que », et « même si » ?

Tags: conjonctions

What is the difference between these conjunctions? Give examples please! :)

- quoique
- bien que
- même si

Comment: Answer to "quoique" and  "bien que" [already given](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/196/quoique-vs-bien-que). ["Même si"](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%AAme_si) can't be confused with the other two.

Answer (score -1):

« Quoique » et « bien que » donnent lieu à un verbe au subjonctif. « Même si » n'est pas suivi du subjonctif.

> Quoique je fasse, tu n'es jamais content.
>
> Bien que ce soit difficile, je ne relâcherai pas.
>
> Je t'aime bien, même si t'es con ;-)

Maintenant, parler de la « différence » entre les deux, pour un français c'est clair.  En anglais :

- *quoique* → whatever
- *bien que* → despite the fact; even though
- *même si* → even if

Comment: Tu confonds _quoique_ et _quoi que_, _even if_ me semble être un gallicisme et quant à la différence d'emploi entre les trois elle est tellement peu claire que j'ai du mal à me décider si elle est purement stylistique ou si une composante sémantique est présente.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: je suis bien d'accord (sauf pour *even if*).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, Précisons. _même si_ + imparfait peut être traduit par _even if_ mais serait un intrus dans la série.  Il me semble que _même si + ind. présent_ fait partie de la série et ne peut pas être traduit par _even if_ (mais plutôt par _even though_, _although_, _nevertheless_, _notwithstanding_, _still_, _while_, _yet_, _albeit_, ... qui sont aussi des candidats pour traduire _quoique_, _bien que_, _malgré que_, ...)  Bon il faut écrire une réponse complète mais elle nécessite de chercher si il y a une nuance ou pas.